# French equivalent of the Japanese expression « c’est comme essayer d'attraper un nuage »

Tags: expressions

In Japanese, you can say "雲をつかむような話", « c’est comme essayer d'attraper un nuage », when you find a plan extremely unrealistic and success seems to elude your grasp despite your best efforts.

How would you express a similar idea in French? Does my sentence below sound idiomatic enough?

> Je ne sais pas par où commencer. J’ai l’impression d’**essayer d’attraper de la fumée**.
>
> ou : essayer d’attraper de la fumée **avec les mains**
>
> ou : essayer d’attraper de la fumée **à mains nues**

Comment: Is this expression used to express someone’s frustration about the impossibility of a plan (perhaps even their own plan) that they originally considered to be valid, but now, “despite [their] best efforts,” they realize is too difficult/impossible; or is it usually directed preemptively [and pejoratively]  toward a cockamamie, pie-in-the-sky plan (& the plan’s architect) that **from the beginning** clearly had little or no chance of working (and therefore no effort [best or otherwise] was ever really wasted on the plan)?

Comment: @PapaPoule Hi. The latter. For instance: Son: When I grow up, I will become President of the United States of America. Mother: C’est tout comme essayer d'attraper un nuage ! Just leave it to Trump.

Comment: Il y a « [faire des châteaux en Espagne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_en_Espagne) » et « poursuivre des chimères » mais ces expressions n'impliquent pas la notion d'efforts.

Comment: C'est une très jolie expression japonaise, merci de la partager avec nous.

Comment: "Faire des châteaux en Espagne", ça a plus une notion de faire des projets grandioses qui n'aboutiront jamais. Il n'y a pas réellement une notion d'action, ni effectivement, d'effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A useless effort can be rendered by the expression *coup d'[épée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9p%C3%A9e) dans l'eau* which is somewhat similar to the Japanese one.

> Je ne sais pas par où commencer, j'ai l'impression de donner des coups d'épée dans l'eau.

There is also *brasser de l'air*, but like my previous suggestion, it applies to an ongoing or past effort, not to a planned one.

Finally, you might use the colloquial *[pisser](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pisser) dans un violon*:

Comment: Can this expression apply to the President example in my comment? Mother: "C'est comme donner **des coups** d'épée dans l'eau !" Incidentally, I suppose you can also say  "C'est comme donner **un coup** d'épée dans l'eau !" Merci.

Comment: I'm afraid not. *Donner un coup d'épée dans l'eau* is used for an ongoing effort you realize to be vain, not that much for a planned one.

Comment: L'expression figée est "comme donner des coups d'épées dans l'eau", on ne parlera pas "d'un" coup d'épée au singulier.

Comment: La réponse est correcte, mais je trouve l'exemple donné pour "Autant pisser dans un violon" un peu mal choisi. Pour moi, "pisser dans un violon", c'est le plus souvent utilisé quand tu essayes de faire entendre quelque chose à quelqu'un, le raisonner, ou faire quelque chose, et que cela zéro effet. ça ne s'applique pas très bien à "Je veux devenir président". ex: Je leur ai envoyé 3 lettres de rappel, mais autant pisser dans un violon! J'ai essayé de la prévenir, mais autant pisser dans un violon!

Comment: "Brasser de l'air" ou "brasser beaucoup d'air", est assez similaire à "pisser dans un violon", sauf qu'on a une notion d'énormément d'activité pour rien. Un peu comme "Beaucoup de bruit pour rien", mais avec une idée d'action.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Je suis assez d'accord pour l'exemple, qui était repris du commentaire de l'OP. Je viens d'ailleurs de le supprimer de ma réponse.

Comment: Notez que l'expression originelle est "souffler dans un violon".

Comment: @wazoox C'est très probable en effet, mais *pisser*, en ajoutant une deuxième couche d'absurdité, s'est imposé.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever analogy you end up using to express your frustration, instead of introducing it with “**J’ai l’impression d'** essayer …” (or even “C’est comme essayer …), another way to begin it would be by using “**Autant** essayer … ” ([I/YOU] Might just as well try …), which I think captures a bit better the notion that the task or idea is so utterly impossible that it’s not even worth trying.

That being said, I think your idea of catching smoke with hands is pretty good:

> Je ne sais pas par où commencer.  Autant essayer d’attraper de la
>   fumée avec les mains.

or borrowing from Peter Pan, you might consider:

> Je ne sais pas par où commencer. Autant essayer d’attraper mon/son/ton
>   ombre.

In fact I think you could probably be understood, if not idiomatic, by using any recognized difficult/impossible task as an analogy, e.g.:

> Je ne sais pas par où commencer. Autant essayer d’assécher l’océan.
>
> Je ne sais pas par où commencer. Autant essayer de compter les étoiles
>   dans le ciel.

Comment: Je pense que la question portait plus sur les expressions qui sont courantes et attestées en français, mais voilà un bel effort d'imagination. J'aime bien "Autant tenter d'attraper ton ombre".

Answer (score 1):

Sans la poésie de l'expression japonaise, je propose:

> Avancer d'un pas et reculer de deux
>
> Pédaler dans la semoule (ou la choucroute)